# window error [error 2] in python when renaming files

Tags: python, rename

When trying to remove zero padding in filenames (i.e. `001.txt` changed to `1.txt` and `012.txt` changed to `12.txt`), I got the following error (referring to the 4th line):

> Windows Error: [Error 2]

Here's my code:

```
import os

for filename in os.listdir("testing"):
    if filename.startswith('00'):
        os.rename(filename,filename[2:])
    elif filename.startswith('0'):
        os.rename(filename,filename[1:])
```

Comment: You can replace your if-elif condition with: `os.rename(filename, filename.lstrip('0'))` and use `glob` module: `glob.glob('*.txt')` to get a list of file names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`filename` contains filename only. (no directory part: `testing`)

You should qualify the path as follow:

```
os.rename(os.path.join('testing', filename),
          os.path.join('testing', filename[2:]))
```

Otherwise, the `os.rename` finds the file in the current working directory, not in `testing` directory.